# What is user agent string for "Internet Download Manager"?

Tags: .htaccess

Would you please let me know that what is user agent string for "Internet Download Manager"?
I want use it in .htaccess.

Comment: [This thing](http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com/)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is aimed at [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Answer (score 3):

Just sniff it. With [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/), for example. Or make apache to write User-Agent to log file.

Comment: Thanks,how can i use wireshark? i surprize that on internet by googling i can't find.

Comment: Hi gelraen; i downloaded and installed wireshark but can't work with it ,and because my speed is low i can't see videos,is there any other solution?thanks

Comment: @gelraen: Can we have a direct answer please? As I tried `Wireshark` but it was only monitoring the traffic thru my browsers and not thru my download manager. Any recommendations?

Answer (score 2):

Answer of mine to another question:

Blocking by user agent is not a good way to go since every decent download manager will send the request with a browser's user-agent header.
For example, IDM 6.06 (current version) send the following user agent for chrome:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/11.0.696.57 Safari/534.24
```

Then again for IE it uses:

```
 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)
```

Guess what IE sends without IDM:

```
 Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.3)
```

Reason is that IDM captures information using a network driver, so basically it 'steals' the request from your web browser and sends the exact information it sends.

Answer (score 1):

I did a check for IDM 6.18 and I found its user-agent string to be:
`Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/4.0)`

Here's a [snapshot](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-B_W8oJCQk6s/UnSf6qiHwoI/AAAAAAAAAmo/dDb7keBC6sI/s800/Capture.JPG) to support the same.

Answer (score 0):

From the description on the product's web site, my strong guess is that this program adopts whatever host browser it works with, so it's likely not to have  a user agent string of its own.

To make sure, you could do a download using this program, and then look into your log files for the User Agent string.